# Is it possible to generate a fat tree by any number of nodes?

Tags: networking, graph, tree, mininet, topology

As my question title suggests, I have a confusion about the fat-tree structure. 
I am trying to write a program, where I get a certain number of nodes as my input and I should generate an output that builds a fat-tree topology out of them.

For example, if my input is 4, my output must represent a fat-tree topology made by 4 nodes(n1,n2,n3,n4)

As far as I could read, fat-tree topology is only dependant on the number of ports rather than the nodes. This is why I am confused about whether it is possible to create a fat-tree structure with the number of nodes as my only input at all!.
I am very new to networking concepts, I would appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 4):

If I understood the question, you have a certain amount of nodes in input, and you want to build a FatTree topology with these nodes.
Unfortunately, you cannot create a complete FatTree topology with an arbitrary number of nodes.
If you are confused about the construction, I suggest to have a look at this [link](https://blogchinmaya.blogspot.com/2017/04/what-is-fat-tree-and-how-to-construct.html)

Comment: Please avoid using links since they sometimes go dead. Please update that with what site you're referring to etc. A short snippet from there is also useful

Answer (score 3):

For my master thesis, I explored some data center topologies and their feasability for network tomography-based monitoring applications. This resultet in a few python models—FatTree included—implemented using the networkx library, that are available on [Github](https://github.com/Cerenia/DC_Topos). The code is not the prettiest, especially the visualisation parts, and could surely be improved, but I hope it can still be useful to gain an intuition about how these topologies scale.

If you start playing around with the different scales of the FatTree you will quickly see, that [Giuseppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9858192/giuseppe) is right. A fat-tree has a very strict structure that is only dependant on the port number parameter. It is therefore indeed not possible to construct a fat-tree with an arbitrary number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm late in answering this, and others have already given the correct answer, I'd still like to add some value with respect to FatTree topology design.

-> For a k-port switch based Fattree topology, you can derive these values by using tree data structure properties and the topology requirements:

```
- number of core switches = (k/2)^2
- number of pods = k
- number of aggregation switches in each pod = k/2
- number of edge switches in each pod = k/2
- each aggregation switch connected to k/2 core switches and k/2 edge switches
- each edge switch connected to k/2 aggregation switches and k/2 nodes
- i.e., each pod consists of (k/2)^2 nodes
- number of nodes possible to be connected to the network = (K^3)/4
```

Since the number of servers possible to be connected to this network is expressed in terms of `k`, now you can clearly see that you can't create a fattree topology with any number of nodes. The count of nodes can only take the forms (k^3)/4 for even values of k (to be integer values), e.g., 16, 54, and so on. So, in other words, you can't have a proper fattree topology with random node count (different than listed above or if not expressed as above)!